# How can I access all material icons in Android Studio through Icon in Jetpack Compose

Tags: image, icons, android-jetpack-compose, android-icons, google-material-icons

Jetpack Compose has an `Icon` composable where I can access an `imageVector`.  See example below.

```
Icon(
     imageVector = Icons.Rounded.Email,
     contentDescription = "Email Icon",
)
```

Why can I not access all icons listed in this Material Icons library through this imageVector.  For example, "wifi_off" can't be accessed.  There is a very limited library accessible via `imageVector`

https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material+Icons&icon.style=Rounded&icon.platform=android

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add the dependency

```
implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:$compose_version"
```

and use:

```
Icon(
    imageVector = Icons.Rounded.WifiOff,
    contentDescription = "Email Icon",
)
```

[image]

As described in the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/icons/package-summary):

> androidx.compose.material.icons  is the entry point for using Material Icons in Compose, designed to provide icons that match those described at **fonts.google.com/icons**.
> The most commonly used set of Material icons are provided by `androidx.compose.material:material-icons-core`.
> A separate library, **androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended**, contains the full set of Material icons.

Comment: After importing this library, my APK size increased by ~5M. As the [Maven Repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.compose.material/material-icons-extended?repo=google) page says "It is a very large dependency and should not be included directly." How could we properly handle this?

Comment: @John6 From official Android documentation: 

`Note that only the most commonly used icons are provided by default. You can add a dependency on androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended to access every icon, but note that due to the very large size of this dependency you should make sure to use R8 / ProGuard to remove unused icons from your application.`

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/icons/Icons

Comment: I have solved the problem. Actually we do not need do anything with ProGuard, the reason why my package size increased is because someone in our team added a rule kept all stuff under package androidx.

Comment: Is there any way to use these `ImageVector`s in legacy code? For example, notifications & widgets. At the moment it seems like we need to use the drawable resources for that which means a lot of doubled-up images.

Answer (score 4):

Huge thanks to **Gabriele Mariotti** for pointing us towards the extended icons library in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75127690/7212563). I would like to post another answer to share how to pull the same thing off if you're managing your dependencies and building your app with Gradle **[the newer way](https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-kotlin-dsl)**.

If:

- Your app module's build script is written in **[Gradle Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html)** in `app/build.gradle.kts`;
- Your dependencies versions are maintained in a **[version catalog](https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-catalogs)** in `gradle/libs.versions.toml`;
- Your Compose libraries dependencies are versioned using the **[Compose BOM](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/bom)** (`compose-bom`);

then I suggest you depend on [Compose Material Icons Extended](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.compose.material/material-icons-extended) like this:

1. **Add this** to the `[libraries]` section of your `gradle/libs.versions.toml`:

```ini
material-icons-extended = { group = "androidx.compose.material", name = "material-icons-extended" }
```

2. **Add this** to the `dependencies` scope in your `app/build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
implementation(libs.material.icons.extended)
```

3. **Sync** your project with your **Gradle** build files.

Now you should be able to **use all** your favourite **Material Icons** in your app **importing them** like this:

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.outlined.Fastfood

// ...

Icon(
    imageVector = Icons.Outlined.Fastfood,
    contentDescription = "Burger and Soda",
)
```